# dask: Closing dangling stream in <TCP How to restart LocalCluster?

Tags: dask

While starting `dask` `LocalCluster` with

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

and after interrupting `jupyter` kernel and rerunning cell  `dask` shows the following warning again and again.

```
distributed.comm.tcp - WARNING - Closing dangling stream in <TCP  local=tcp://127.0.0.1:49408 remote=tcp://127.0.0.1:37487>
```

Restarting kernel does not help.

How to restart `LocalCluster` to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you kill the Dask cluster in some unexpected way then yes, you might get warnings like this.  They are ok and should not seriously affect things.

If you want to close things cleanly, you can call the close method.

```
cluster.close()
```

Comment: This does not help in my case for some reason